# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am getting element is not attached to the page document error for the above code. Moreover I want to know how to handle elements which 'appear' as a result of an action on the target page.

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/loginHome.jsf");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign up")).click();

    //Verify whether the navigation is to the correct page
    String title=driver.getTitle();
    if (title.equals("IRCTC Next Generation eTicketing System")){
    driver.findElement(By.id("userRegistrationForm:userName")).sendKeys("abcdef");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Check Availability")).click();

    WebElement text=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='userRegistrationForm:useravail']"));
    boolean availability=text.isDisplayed();
    try {if(availability==true){
    System.out.println("The user id is available. Please enter other details to complete registration");
    }}

    catch (NoSuchElementException e){
    System.out.println("The user id is not available. Please enter a different user ID.");
    }
    }
    else
    System.out.println("You are on a wrong page");

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom wait to handle the element that will appear because of an action. So technically speaking, you are waiting for an expected condition to be true.

```
private void waitForElement(String element) {
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, 10); // Wait for 10 seconds.
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(element)));
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(element));
 element.click(); // The element is now present and can now be clicked
}
```

In the above code you know the string / xpath of the element. You can pass it into this method and will wait for 10 seconds for the execpected conditon to become true. When it is true, the element can then be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than catching an exception, the preferred way is to use `.findElements()` (plural) and then check for empty. If the collection is empty, the element doesn't exist on the page. If it exists, grab `.get(0)` and use it.

I added a few other optimizations to your code. I would do something more like this.

```
driver.get("http://toolsqa.com/automation-practice-table/");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign up")).click();

// Verify whether the navigation is to the correct page
if (driver.getTitle().equals("IRCTC Next Generation eTicketing System"))
{
    driver.findElement(By.id("userRegistrationForm:userName")).sendKeys("abcdef");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Check Availability")).click();

    List<WebElement> text = driver.findElements(By.id("userRegistrationForm:useravail"));
    if (!text.isEmpty())
    {
        // element found
        if (text.get(0).isDisplayed())
        {
            System.out.println("The user id is available. Please enter other details to complete registration");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // element NOT found
        System.out.println("The user id is not available. Please enter a different user ID.");
    }
}
else
{
    System.out.println("You are on a wrong page");
}
```

If you perform some action and then need to wait for an element to appear, you can use `WebDriverWait`. An example is below that waits for a `BUTTON` to be visible and clicks it.

```
By buttonLocator = By.id("theButtonId");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(buttonLocator));
button.click();
```

There are many other options under [`ExpectedConditions`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) that you should check out in the docs linked.